# I need your comments on my php if statment

Tags: php, sql

I have problem with my php if statement.

I have two price tables in SQL, some of the articles has prices in 1st price table (as price1) while some of the articles has prices in 2nd table as `$price2`. I have read and save the prices in price1 and price2. Now I need to find the price of articles.

```
if ($price1 > 0){$price = $price1; 
}
else if ($price2> 0){ $price = $price2;
}
```

The articles take the prices from `$price1` but not from `$price2`, when there is price in `$price2`, it takes the price of last article that has price in `$price1`.

If I change the order of if statement then it does viceversa.

Is there any other way to right this statement?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. Improve it!

Comment: After this conditional, you need to reset the `$price1` and `$price2` variables to initial values.

Comment: duplicate, of the one you deleted 5 minutes ago, for some reason

Comment: Yes i reposted it, because it requires modification and i deleted the other one.
@ Joe; could you please explain a bit?

Comment: You only have to click *edit* in your questions. [Help] for more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because you have not initialized `$price`, `$price1`, `$price2` before using them every time.

Please initialize `$price1` and `$price2` to zero before querying your tables.